# Elements with unwanted draggable behaviour

Tags: html, css, border, draggable

in this snippet I've made a 4x4 grid

This grid have some strange behaviour though : when you "mousedown" on some tile and then move your mouse the grid act like a draggable image (but not all the tiles "travels" with the drag semitransparent feedback...).

How can I prevent this behaviour?

```css
.line{
white-space:nowrap;
}
.tile{
width:25px;
height:25px;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="line"><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div></div>
    <div class="line"><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div></div>
    <div class="line"><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div></div>
    <div class="line"><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out it seems to be the selection that makes the elements draggable (weird because it happens even if nothing has been selected (highlighted))

A working solution is to prevent the elements from being selected like so:

```
.tile, .tile::after, .tile::before {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
cursor: default;
}
```